# CodeIgniter 4 POST routes not working in production shared hosting on Hostinger

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, post, codeigniter-4

My CodeIgnater 4 is **not recognizing POST routes** when I try them in my **shared hosting server on Hostinger**. Everything else works as expected and the **POST routes work fine on my local server**.

The tests I made in differents browsers:

- Simple html form. *Result:* Form make a GET request instead of POST.
- Form helper form. *Result:* Form make a GET request instead of POST.
- Ajax call. *Result:* Returns the same page for some reason.
- **Direct POST call from an API Rest Testing web: *Result:* 404 File Not found**
- Change the `$route->post` to `$route->get` or `$route->add`. *Result:* The route is found but with a GET request and without data.
- Using `index.php` at the end of my address, leads to the same above results.

I've tried almost everything solution I've seen on the internet like:

- Changes in my `.htaccess`
- `$uriProtocol` in each posible value
- Activate csrf
- Change my `base_url` to different formats like:

  - [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
  - http://www.example.com
  - http://www.example.com/
  - http://example.com

**Server files structure on hostinger Shared Hosting:**

```
domains
  mydomain.com
    public_html (all files from CI's public folder are here)
    app
    system
    .env
    (others CI files/folders...)
```

**.htaccess file:**

```
# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
    # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
    RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to the front controller, index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

    # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

# Disable server signature start
    ServerSignature Off
# Disable server signature end
```

**Routes file:**

```
<?php

namespace Config;

// Create a new instance of our RouteCollection class.
$routes = Services::routes();

// Load the system's routing file first, so that the app and ENVIRONMENT
// can override as needed.
if (file_exists(SYSTEMPATH . 'Config/Routes.php'))
{
    require SYSTEMPATH . 'Config/Routes.php';
}

/**
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Router Setup
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
$routes->setDefaultNamespace('App\Controllers');
$routes->setDefaultController('Home');
$routes->setDefaultMethod('index');
$routes->setTranslateURIDashes(false);
$routes->set404Override();
$routes->setAutoRoute(false);

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Route Definitions
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

// We get a performance increase by specifying the default
// route since we don't have to scan directories.
$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');

$routes->get('/pages/testRest', 'Pages::testRest');
$routes->get('/pages/showHazardLevel', 'Pages::showHazardLevel');
$routes->post('/pages/create', 'Pages::create');
// $routes->get('/pages/create', 'Pages::create');

$routes->get('/migrateLast/(:any)', 'Pages::migrateLast/$1');
$routes->post('/userAuthentication', 'Pages::userAuthentication');

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Additional Routing
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * There will often be times that you need additional routing and you
 * need it to be able to override any defaults in this file. Environment
 * based routes is one such time. require() additional route files here
 * to make that happen.
 *
 * You will have access to the $routes object within that file without
 * needing to reload it.
 */
if (file_exists(APPPATH . 'Config/' . ENVIRONMENT . '/Routes.php'))
{
    require APPPATH . 'Config/' . ENVIRONMENT . '/Routes.php';
}
```

Comment: It is not about the codeigniter code but may because of configuration settings, htaccess or firewall rules of hosting provider. I can not tell you the exact reason actually you have given very less information to check. Need your website url, htaccess code first to check if it can be identified

Comment: @VirenderKumar hi and thank you for answering. I have edited the Question and added some files like the .htaccess

Comment: Can you share your live website url please?
and tell me the server also is it centos or apache?

Comment: Hello @Skipydie, I was facing the same issue. Later I figured out that there was some redirection code for those particular routes where I was trying to send POST requests. So just make sure your .htaccess doesn't have any unnecessary code.